# Haskell Yesod concurrency performance

Tags: haskell, concurrency, yesod

I really confused after **ab** concurrency testing simple Yesod Blog from:
http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Yesod-tutorial-for-newbies/

Testing for static page:

```
ab -c 30000 -n 30000 http://localhost:3000/
```

all requests - OK

```
ab -c 1000 -n 1000 http://localhost:3000/blog
```

96% - Failed requests

```
ab -c 100 -n 100 http://localhost:3000/blog
```

20% - Failed requests

with message:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2014:17:28:25 +0300] "GET /blog HTTP/1.0" 500 1416 "" "ApacheBench/2.3"
07/Oct/2014:17:28:25 +0300 [Error#yesod-core] <socket: 10>: hClose: resource vanished (Broken pipe) @(yesod-core-1.2.17:Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod ./Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:503:5)
```

As DB I used **MongoDB**

OK, then I tried:

```
ab -c 100 -n 100 http://www.haskellers.com/
```

20% - Failed requests

```
ab -c 1000 -n 1000 http://www.haskellers.com/
```

66% - Failed requests

**And my question**: why so many rejections for Concurrency requests?! For example Node.js for same functionality:
*ab -c 7000 -n 7000 = OK*

Comment: You need to tell us more about the environment. GHC version, library version, OS etc.

Comment: If you're asking why 1000 concurrent requests to the haskellers.com server would result in a large number of failed requests, it's likely because your requests look a lot like a DoS attack.

Comment: @DonStewart ghc: 7.6.3
Yesod 1.2
Ubuntu 11.10 - any more?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman - concurrency 100 and 20% failed request DDoS?!! Simply i want to know what can I do to increase responses with DB to 100% with -c 30000

Comment: I'm talking about the haskellers.com request, not the local one. Locally there wouldn't be any DoS protections in place. I'd recommend posting the actual code you're running (likely as a Github repo). It's possible that it's a problem in the database connection layer if this is MongoDB-specific. Have you tried this with MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: Are you using `yesod devel` or otherwise a development mode Yesod? In production mode I get slightly better performance on my local machine.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Thank you for the response. I tested with at Production mod with MySQL, PgSQL - and have got success about 20k concurrency. But some reason MongoDB return errors.
But I discover some strange fact. With MySQL/PgSQL or without them with concurrency my latency multiplied. For example: -c 1 response at browser ~1.2ms, -c 100: ~120ms, -c 1000: 1.2 sec. Is that normal?! I tried same at Node.js (simply for testing) and my latency time is same with different parametres '-c'... Any ideas? ))

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors: the machine you're using, if you're testing from the same machine or a different one, how you compiled the app, runtime options, library versions, and of course the code itself... There's not nearly enough information to figure things out here.